# Internet Explorer negative margin clipping div

Tags: css, internet-explorer, margin

EDIT: you can view the page here: http://websitem.gazi.edu.tr/test/index.html

I'm trying to do the effect in the screenshot below:

[image: Chrome/Firefox in top. IE 7/8/9 below]

The first one is from Chrome. Firefox show the same. But Internet Explorer from version 7 up to 9 shows the second picture.

My html structure is this:

```
<div class="header-menu">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="header-curve"></div>
        <div class="header-building"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And my css is this (dont bother with LESS specific syntax)

```
.header-menu {
    #gradient > .vertical(@baseColor, @baseColorDark);
    height: 82px;
    margin-top: 82px;

    .header-curve {
        background: @baseColor url(/ui/frontend/themes/default/ui/img/header-curve.png) center top no-repeat;
        height: 82px;
        margin-top: -82px;
        width: 1020px;
    }

    .header-building {
        background: url(/ui/frontend/themes/default/ui/img/header-building.png) 20px top no-repeat;
        height: 214px;
        margin-top: -82px;
        width: 1000px;
    }
}
```

how can i solve the problem with IE? i already tried position: relative and zoom:1 fixes.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you explain why you are using margin-top:-82px? Personally I've almost never have had the need for negative margin, I'm pretty sure there's a much better solution.

Comment: 82px is the height of the blue curve. there are 2 images. the curve is full white opaque except a half ellipse which gets the blue color from header-menu class. the other image is the building with all white shadows and effects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the filter style on your `.header-menu` class is causing it to be hidden in IE, is this necessary?

Comment: When I look at your page with IE Developer Tools, it shows a filter style applied to `header-menu` with: `progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#1e5085', endColorstr='#15315b', GradientType=0)`.  When I disable this style it shows up fine.

Answer (score 0):

I think you were on the right track with the `position: relative;`, but also add a `z-index` value in there (play with the value until it appears correctly).

Answer (score 0):

I might be missing something, but I still don't understand why you're bothering with the negative margin. The following CSS would do exactly the same, no?

```
.header-menu {
    #gradient > .vertical(@baseColor, @baseColorDark);

    .header-curve {
        background: @baseColor url(/ui/frontend/themes/default/ui/img/header-curve.png) center top no-repeat;
        height: 82px;
        width: 1020px;
    }

    .header-building {
        background: url(/ui/frontend/themes/default/ui/img/header-building.png) 20px top no-repeat;
        height: 214px;
        width: 1000px;
    }
}
```

Comment: here it is. it's slimmed down version: http://websitem.gazi.edu.tr/test/index.html